# Alfresco email attachment came link not a file?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

In Alfresco community edition-5.1.x email attachment using webscript script is execute successfully email received but attachment not working its show like this please refer image below,

[image]

Please help any one to help make as separate attachment file not link?

Answer (score 1):

Attachment email works fine, as it should be and as designed.

If you would like to attach file to the email you need to customize alfresco, there is many discussions on Alfresco forum. Also I would check this blog post  http://savicprvoslav.blogspot.ca/2010/10/send-html-email-from-alfresco-33-with.html

Comment: I tried download the which they provide the link when a click there is no jar file , please which jar file their used for this